# Can I use a colon after "for instance"?

Tags: colons

For instance + "colon".

Take Bartlett pears, for instance: unless they are treated with exactly the right amount of 1-MCP at exactly the right time, they will remain hard and green until they rot, and consumers who experience this will be unlikely to purchase them again.

I remember being told that we typically don't use a colon after for example or for instance, instead we use a comma. I am more familiar with "Take Bartlett pears, for instance, unless they are... Why is using a colon correct?

Comment: (This question is from Khan Academy SAT Practice Test 3 (Question #29). I found that answer weird too.)

Comment: I find the exact same sentence on SAT reading question so I guess you are working on that. The correct answer is Take Bartlett pears, for instance: unless... So I think there is a comma in front of "for instance" and a colon after it.

Answer (score 1):

You use a colon to **introduce a series of items, or expand on your point**, and it actually effectively means "for instance" or "for example" already in this style of usage, so saying "for instance:" is actually redundant.  Similarly you've already said that "Bartlett pears" are an example of something with your usage of the word "take", so it's arguable doubly redundant to say "Take X, for instance:".

You would more properly write

*"Take Bartlett pears: unless they are treated ..."*

Read more about colon usage here: it's something that a lot of people get wrong.

http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/colons.asp

Comment: Thank you for clarifying Max. I can see why it is redundant. Do you mind if I asked 2 quick follow up questions?

1) If we just looked at the phrase "Take Bartlett pears". Would you say that it is a complete sentence or a run-on? 

2) I recall that colons are used only between two independent sentences. So I have my second question is if "Take Bartlett pears, for instance" is a complete sentence.

Comment: "Take Bartlett pears" on its own doesn't work, i think: it leaves the reader hanging, waiting for you to say something about them.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with a little double redundancy.

Comment: You say more properly write, which is exactly what the OP posted as right.  I call this the emphatic colon, used with a full sentence. That SAT style ain't the best.

Answer (score 1):

In this case "for instance" is about "Take Bartlett pears" not about the rest of the sentence beginning with "unless......". Put the "for instance" at the beginning of the sentence and it will be clear to you. Like that: "For instance,take Barlett pears:unless they are treated....".So, if you going to change the place of "for instance", it doesn't mean that you have to remove colon.The reason why I haven't mentioned redundancy of "for instance" is that, the question asked by author is the SAT question and there is not any option without "for instance".